# Can AngularJS $modal service (ui.bootstrap.modal) be made to block synchronously?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the AngularJS $modal service (ui.bootstrap.modal) to present a dialog box:

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'resources/qad/qraview/view/qModalDialog.html',
  controller: qModalDialogController,
  backdrop: 'static',  
  keyboard: false,  
  resolve: {
    modalOptions: function () {
      return $scope.modalOptions;
    }
  }
});
```

The call to $modal.open is asynchronous and returns immediately. Because of the flow of my program I need $modal.open to block until the user has dismissed the dialog box either by clicking "OK" or "Cancel".  Is there any way to make $modal.open be synchronous?

Comment: No. Get used to asynchronous calls and promises. That's how JavaScript works.

Comment: Is this a separate dialog box that the user has to dismiss?  Doesn't `$modal.open` create the dialog box?

Comment: `$modal.open` returns a promise as a part of its `result` property, you can use that to chain your logic..

Answer (score 3):

Use the promise returned by the result property (as PSL also stated). The code would then look something like this:

```
$modal.open({
     templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
     controller: 'ModalDialogController', 
})
.result.then(
    function () {
        alert("OK");
    }, 
    function () {
        alert("Cancel");
    }
);
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adnu6mmt/2/)

Comment: This won't work if you want to focus something in the modal as on iOS this needs to be done in a synchronous reaction to user input (e.g. clicking a button).